# Unable to build docker file c# - Visual Studio 2019

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2019

After creating and developing WEB Api in c#, I wanted to add docker file and run API in docker container.

My docker file is named Dockerfile, with content like this:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebAPI/WebAPI.csproj", "WebAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebAPI/WebAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebAPI"
RUN dotnet build "WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebAPI.dll"]
```

After building docker file, the Visual Studio code is promted this message in console:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CTC1014 Docker command failed with exit code 1.
The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet build "WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build' returned a non-zero code: 1   WebAPI  c:\devops projekti\web api gir\webapi\dockerfile    1
```

Comment: what happens if you run `dotnet build .... ` command manually from the command prompt directly..

Comment: 0 error(s) after building project
Also tried with `docker build -t counter-image -f Dockerfile .`, I get this error: `Step 7/17 : COPY ["WebAPI/WebAPI.csproj", "WebAPI/"]
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat WebAPI\WebAPI.csproj: file does not exist`